# Test program to configure MPLS datapath in Latest Kernel 4.1.3

Tags: linux, routing, kernel

Latest Kernel supports MPLS datapath in kernel, However there is no test program, or any guide how to write user space program to configure a MPLS datapath in kernel.

I browse the kernel code and found new address family is defined AF_MPLS and we can add new mpls route, delete mpls route and get mpls routes in/from the kernel.

```
#define PF_MPLS     AF_MPLS
rtnl_register(PF_MPLS, RTM_NEWROUTE, mpls_rtm_newroute, NULL, NULL);
rtnl_register(PF_MPLS, RTM_DELROUTE, mpls_rtm_delroute, NULL, NULL);
rtnl_register(PF_MPLS, RTM_GETROUTE, NULL, mpls_dump_routes, NULL);
```

Please provide guidance from where I can get the test program or How can I write the test program to configure MPLS datapath in Kernel.

Comment: im not pretty sure if this question belongs to Superuser.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be not be much official documentation yet. [This blog post](http://pieknywidok.blogspot.de/2015/12/mpls-testbed-on-ubuntu-linux-with.html) explains how to setup a test network with two LERs (as separate network namespaces) and a LSR.

Comment: External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not be useful.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.